# Using Selenium I am trying to scrape a value off a website span HTML

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape the website to eventually return back the "+2.5" value in the span class that is shown but am having a lot of issues getting the CSS SELECTOR to work properly and return that value.

I know this is far off but this was the best I could come up with but returned way too many values and made it impossible to sort:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.book-cell__odds > span')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: 1]

I have tried a number of different setups for the CSS SELECTOR but have not found any that are working the way I need

Comment: Could you please share more infos , which website are you scraping or what is your code. But generally you have to use class attribute. (BY.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.book-cell(it doesn't seem in picture))

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the relevant HTML and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the whole page but one issue I see with your current locator is that you will return both SPANs in the posted HTML instead of just the first that contains "+2.5". You can further focus your CSS selector to just get the first span adding `:first-of-type`.

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.book-cell__odds > span:first-of-type')
```

If that still doesn't get you what you want, you'll probably have to provide a link to the page.

More info on [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type).

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

The value ***+2.5*** is within the first desendant `<span>` of it's parent `<div>`

---

### Solution

To print the text ***+2.5*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*, *`first-child`* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.book-cell__odds > span:first-child"))).text)
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*, *`first-of-type`* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.book-cell__odds > span:first-of-type"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)